# Parsing KML coordinates from Google Maps - PHP

Tags: php, regex, kml, google-earth, kmz

I try to collect the coordinates (longitude and latitude) from the Google KML file with PHP.

```
<Point>
    <coordinates>45.51088930166307,52.52216552154544</coordinates>
</Point>
```

I can explode the coordinates with comma and get results as below:

```
[0] => 45.51088930166307
[1] => 52.52216552154544
```

To get this results I'm using:

```
explode(',', $coordinates);
```

How do I explode the coordinates with commas?

```
<Point>
    <coordinates>45.51088930166307,51,52.52216552154544,75</coordinates>
</Point>
```

Results that I need:

```
[0] => 45.51088930166307,51
[1] => 52.52216552154544,75
```

And how do I remove the digits after commas?

```
[0] => 45.51088930166307
[1] => 52.52216552154544
```

Thanks,

Comment: Get length/2, and cut it

Comment: @VasylZhuryk won't work if the number after the first comma has different lengths. Ex `x.xx,99,x.xx,100`

Comment: Why down votes? Is the question repeated?

Comment: Thanks Vasyl Zhuryk and Andreas for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split the string with a comma that is followed with digits and a dot:

```
preg_split('~,(?=\d+\.)~', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p54m8z/1).

**Details**

- `,` - a comma that  is ...
- `(?=\d+\.)` - immediately followed with 1 or more digits (`\d+`) and a dot (`\.`).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/TzDmcG):

```
$s = '45.51088930166307,51,52.52216552154544,75';
$res = preg_split('~,(?=\d+\.)~', $s);
print_r($res);
// => Array ( [0] => 45.51088930166307,51 [1] => 52.52216552154544,75 )
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew ! This work great. Do you have any idea's how do I remove the digits after commas?
// => Array ( [0] => 45.51088930166307 [1] => 52.52216552154544)

Comment: @HossamEdani Use `preg_match_all('~\d+\.\d+~', $s, $matches)`, see [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9x4rKJ).

Comment: Thank you so much @Wiktor Stribiżew! This one work great too! 
I used your way with preg_split and then explode it with comma and ignored the part after comma
$coordinates  = '45.51088930166307,51,52.52216552154544,75';
$longitude =  explode(",", preg_split('~,(?=\d+\.)~', $coordinates)[0])[0];
$latitude = explode(",", preg_split('~,(?=\d+\.)~', $coordinates)[1])[0];
https://ideone.com/03vJoE
Your answers were very useful and helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A non regex solution is to use strpos to find the position of the second comma and split the string there.

```
$str = "45.51088930166307,51,52.52216552154544,75";
if(substr_count($str, ",")>1){
    $pos = strpos($str, ",", strpos($str, ",")+1); // find second comma
    // The inner strpos finds the first comma and uses that as the starting point to find the second comma.
    $arr = [substr($str, 0,$pos), substr($str,$pos+1)]; //split string at second comma
}else{
    $arr = explode(",", $str);
}
var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/nnrlV

Comment: Thanks for you answer, 
This not working if one of the coordinates doesn't has comma
Condition 1:
$str = "45.51088930166307,52.52216552154544,75";
Condition 2:
$str = "45.51088930166307,51,52.52216552154544";
I think we need to count the commas first and then split it.

Comment: this way work very fine as the one of Wiktor Stribiżew. I used the way of Wiktor Stribiżew because it's a bit shorter in code but this one good too. Your answer is highly appreciated. Thanks alot!